# Which is better to execute window.setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Which option is better to execute window.setTimeout and why?

Option A:

```
window.setTimeout(somefunc,0);
```

Option B:

```
window.setTimeout(somefunc,n); //n may be any number >0
```

Thanks.

Comment: For what purpose?  There are reasons to do both!

Comment: Would you mind to tell me the reasons?

What I am doing with somefunc:
I have few frames(1~6) and I make those frames editable using designmode="on".

After that I set contents (from database) in those frames. But unfortunately, contents are not always loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing about a timeout or an interval, they always wait for the current thread to run out before they execute their own function- even if you put it in the first line.

```
var color='white';
setTimeout(function(){alert(color+' from timeout')}, 0);
for(var i=0;i<100001;++i){
    if(i=100000)alert(color='green');
}
alert(color='red')
```

Comment: Nice example, if I have two setTimeout, then which will be executed first?

Comment: setTimeout simply puts the callback in the event queue, so for multiple setTimeout with 0 delay, they will be executed in the order they appeared lexically in your code

Answer (score 1):

Option A will simply call `somefunc` with the additional overhead of needlessly calling `setTimeout` (since your second parameter means *0 milliseconds of delay*). Option B is for if you intend to have a delay prior to the execution of `somefunc`. Could you elaborate a bit please, or does this answer your question?

Comment: I have few frames(1~6) and I make those frames editable using designmode="on". After that I set contents (from database) in those frames. But unfortunately, contents are not always loaded.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do.

`setTimeout(somefunc,0)` is not so different with just calling somefunc
(but I guess `.setTimeout(somefunc,0)` will finish current block first and then called `somefunc`)

If you need to wait browser rendering, and run `somefunc` after that, use `window.onload` or jQuery's `$(document).ready`

Comment: Instead of using somefunc() if I use setTimeout(somefunc,n) , then somefunc executes.It executes whether I put the delay "0" or any other value.

Comment: @Hoque, the 2nd parameter just determines how long the "new thread" waits before firing somefunc().  If you don't "need" a new thread... just call somefunc()

Comment: true, it is single threaded... that's why "new thread" was in quotes.  setTimeout and setInterval basically allow you run 2 or more bits of code simutaneously.

Comment: if single thread, then what will happen to the old thread? Will the old thread die and new thread will start?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.setTimeout(somefunc,0);
```

will run somefunc right away (but won't wait for a return value before continuing)

```
window.setTimeout(somefunc,n);
```

will wait n milliseconds before running somefunc (but won't wait for it to start or return before continuing)

or if you call `somefunc()` without the timeout it will run somefunc but wait for it to finish before continuing.

consider setTimeout to be like "starting" a new thread.

Comment: "won't wait for a return value", what is the return value. I am not clear about that. Would you mind to tell me more about the return value?

Comment: any time you call a function it can return a value. e.g. `var name = getUserName();` could set `name` with a value returned from `getUserName()`. Even if you don't want or care to return a value... code after your call to `somefunc()` would not execute until somefunc was finished.  By using setTimeout, you tell the browser you don't want to wait... continue executing code... and run  somefunc() after `n` milliseconds.

Comment: So far I know that Javascript is single threaded. "consider setTimeout to be like "starting" a new thread." -then will it be multi-threaded?

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of saying "thread" - one should say "current call stack". And as for single-threaded-ness, we could argue web workers to be some form of user-accessible multi-threading but yes nonetheless even with web workers, the communication between "threads" will be strictly message passing and thus no (technical) concurrency issue would arise. E.g. the webworker can return you something but it can't go and change the DOM itself.

Comment: "will run somefunc right away" IS WRONG.. nope it will run after the current call stack has unrolled (and there was no other event added by the browser in the event queue before we called setTime(func, 0)

Answer (score 0):

I recall having some browser issues when using `setTimeout (func, 0)` so now I do `setTimeout (func, 1)` whenever I want to have the shortest delay. Note that for most (all?) browsers the real shortest delay is some number `n > 1` (definately `n > 0` and probably `n < 50`).

Which browser I was having issues with I don't remember.

Answer (score 0):

Note setTimeout(fn,0) doesn't necessarily ensure that the function fn will be called right after the current callstack unrolls - might not be a very important distinction.

It **IS** possible for the browser to have put something on the event **before** your code hit 
setTimeout(fn, 0) [maybe the code preceding the setTimeout involved some CPU intensive calculations]. [See example here](http://jsfiddle.net/ustamansangat/kzJjJ/)

```
function clickHandler () {
    spinWait(1000);
    setTimeout(relayFunc, 0);
    //the jsFiddle link shows that relayFunc
    //will not be called after the clickHandler
    //if another event was queued during spinWait()
}
```

For a usage of setTimeout other than the common 'let dom elements render first', see [my blog here](http://tshrestha.blogspot.com/2013/03/settimeoutfn-0-for-batching-requests-to.html)